# What's the variance of this random variable?

Tags: random-variables

There's a random variable given:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\rm {X}_i & -2 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
\hline 
\rm{p}_i & 0,1 & 0,5 & 0,3 & 0,1 \\\hline\end{array}$$

The variance I calculated is: 2.56 or 2.24 depending on what formula I use. This is weird and I want to verify.

Comment: What formula did you use?

Comment: I used sum((x_i-E(X))^2*p_i) and E(X^2)*E^2(X)

Comment: The correct variance is $2.56$. Of course each method will give this.

Comment: I get 2.56 also

Comment: @TomDavies92 : Do you perchance mean $E(X^2)- [E(X)]^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my calculation done two ways

$$
\sum x_k p_k = 0.8 ~~~ \hbox{and}~~~ \sum x_k^2 p_k = 3.2, ~~~ 3.2-0.8^2 = 2.56
$$

The other way is
$$
\sum (x_k-0.8)^2 p_k = 2.56
$$

Sorry for using the decimal point instead of the comma!